# Given a formula in Minkowski spacetime, how can we transform it so it works in curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, covariance

To bring a concrete example, let's say I know that the stress-energy tensor related to the electromagnetic field in flat spacetime is

$$T_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\lambda}F_{\nu}^{\;\lambda} - \frac{1}{4}\eta_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}$$

I would like to have this formula working in curved spacetime. I know that I will need to use the appropriate metric ($g_{\mu\nu}$). My question would be: is this a simple switch, as such:

$$T_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\lambda}F_{\nu}^{\;\lambda} - \frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}$$

Or do I need to do something else as well in order be able use the formula in curved spacetime?

Comment: nope, that's basically it.  Convert partial derivatives to covariant derivatives, convert $\eta$ to $g$ and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better yet, you can derive this by starting with the Lagrangian:

$$L = \sqrt{|g|}\left(\frac{1}{16\pi}R + \frac{1}{4}F^{ab}F_{ab}\right)$$

And just finding the equations of motion (I recommend cheating and just "remembering" that the variation of $\sqrt{|g|}R$ with respect to $g_{ab}$ is the Einstein tensor, though).

Comment: Thank you, will try to do this as well!